# How to send form data on each page to different email address from database

Tags: mysql, pdo, foreach, while-loop, phpmailer

I create a web site like booking where on each page I have two forms. However, if I have just two recipients this forms work very well with AJAX, jQuery, PHP validation, PHPMailer and MySQL, but in second form I have problem, because on each page I need change email recipients which I need get from database using PDO, so I'm try the seguent lines of code, but this send form data to all emails from table owners_email which contain email addresses.

```
    $sql="SELECT email_address FROM neum.owners_email";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $mail->AddAddress($row[email_address]);
    }
```

However, I understand why, because my sql query it's select all emails but I need to select for each page different email address and again how to use it in INSERT statement, because in table with form data I have referenced to email_address_id from table with email addresses, how you can see bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `neum`.`owners_email` (
  `email_address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_address` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email_address_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 3
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT = 'Table with information about email addresses of owners.';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `neum`.`form_data`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `neum`.`form_data` (
  `form_data_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `tel` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `from` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `to` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `mail` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `message` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `email_address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`form_data_id`),
  INDEX `fk_form_data_idx` (`email_address_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_form_data`
    FOREIGN KEY (`email_address_id`)
    REFERENCES `neum`.`owners_email` (`email_address_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT = 'Table with information about form data.';
```

Nevertheless, I'm try on google to find answer for this question, but probably nobody use PHPMailer for send email on each page to different email address, because on every my question google usually show me simple results like how to send mail or how to send multiple mails, but for my question dont exist answer, so if somebody know how to fix it thanks in advance for your help and for your appreciate time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer doesn't care who you send to – it just uses whatever you pass to `addAddress()`. If you want to send to different people, you need to figure out how to do get the list of addresses you want to send to, which is entirely independent of later sending them messages. Treat it as two independent tasks:

First task: get a list of addresses. This has nothing to do with PHPMailer.

Second task: send a message to an array of addresses. This has nothing to do with your database.

As it happens, [PHPMailer provides an example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that combines both of these tasks you should be able to adapt. Just because you're sending to 2 people rather than 10,000 doesn't mean you're not sending to a list, and the same code will work fine.

The only thing missing from your first code snippet is something in your MySQL query to limit who it selects for sending. Adapt it by doing something like:

```
$sql="SELECT email_address FROM owners_email JOIN form_data ON form_data.email_address_id = owners_email.id WHERE form_data_id = " . $form_data_id;
```

How you get the right `$form_data_id` value is up to you, and you might want to consider using a join table so that you can have any number of addresses associated with any number of pages, rather than just a single fixed one.

Comment: Dear Synchro thanks a lot for give me some instructions. I'm try to change sql query, but now this don't send email to nobody. You are probably forget to write the name of id correctly, insted "JOIN form_data ON form_data.email_address_id = owners_email.id " probably need be "JOIN form_data ON form_data.email_address_id = owners_email.email_address_id  because every my id starts with name of table, but however any solution doesn't work....

Comment: Yes that's correct - I'm used to tables using just `id` as identifiers. Regardless, don't even look at the email sending code before you're sure you have your queries correct. Test them by themselves (e.g. in a tool like phpMyAdmin, Sequel Pro, etc) to make sure you're getting the right results *before* you try sending. Email is not an effective way to debug SQL statements!

Comment: Dear Synchro, I look everywhere, but can not find solution. However, this examples that you give me by [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) use mysqli and I use PDO, which is completelly different, so perhaps I dont know mysqli, because when I study everybody told that PDO is better, so I just learn and use PDO. Even don't look never something when starts with mysql or mysqli.

Comment: It’s only the functions you call that are different; the query you run will be identical. It should make no practical difference.

Comment: Hm? I don't understand it, so do you know how to insert data into this table with foreign keys. Before I added table with emails I used
``` $mail = "INSERT INTO form_data (name, tel, from, to, email, message) VALUES (:name, :tel, :from, :to, :email, :message)";
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($mail);
 $stmt->execute(['name' => $name, 'tel' => $tel, 'from' => $from, 'to' => $to, 'email' => $email, 'message' => $message]); ``` , but now I column email_address_id, so can not understand how on each page table can know which email_address_id choose. so complicated...

Comment: It's really not complicated. Define an identifier for each page, something like `$page_id = 'home'` in each page script, then use that value in your DB query.

Comment: This is my website. [visit-neum.com](https://visit-neum.com) So if you look maybe understand better. Actually work just red button for contact me and form for Hotel Villa Matić, because in this used two different mail instance, and so just change AddRecipients, but for this second form I need change sql query and whatewer try doesnt work...

Comment: "Just doesn't work" doesn't give me anything to go on. You need to report exactly what your problem is, show your results and debug output, in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you to everyone who gave me guidelines on how to solve my problem of sending emails to addresses from the database.
With a little delay, finally, I want to give an answer to this question, which has bothered me for days, but now it seems so simple to me, because the whole explanation is also on the [official page of phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). The code also contains a code for inserting data into the database. So, complete code it's bellow:

```
$sql = "SELECT owners_email.email_address_id, email_address, owner_name, owner_property, owner_sex, owner_type FROM visitneum.owners_email INNER JOIN visitneum.pages ON (pages.email_address_id = owners_email.email_address_id) WHERE `owner_sex`='M' AND `owner_type`='other' AND `pages_id` = ?";
    $dbstmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $dbstmt->bindParam(1,$pages_id);
    $dbstmt->execute();
    
    $emails = $dbstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(is_array($emails) && count($emails) > 0){
        foreach ($emails as $email){
            $mail->addAddress($email['email_address']);
                $body_other = "<p>Dear {$email['owner_name']}, <br>" . "You just received a message from the site <a href='https://www.visit-neum.com'>visit-neum.com</a><br>Details of your message are below:</p><p><strong>From: </strong>" . ucwords($fname) . "<br><strong>Phone: </strong>" . $tel . "<br><strong>E-mail: </strong>" .strtolower($userMail)."<br><strong>Message: </strong>" . $userMessage . ";
                $mail->Body = $body_other;
                
                try {
                    $mail->send();
                    //Insert data into db
                    $mail = "INSERT INTO visitneum.contact_owner (fname, tel, userMail, userMessage, email_address_id) VALUES (:fname, :tel, :userMail, :userMessage, :email_address_id)";
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($mail);
                    $stmt->execute(['fname' => $fname, 'tel' => $tel, 'userMail' => $userMail, 'userMessage' => $userMessage, 'email_address_id' => $email['email_address_id']]);
                    echo "Thanks ".ucwords($fname)."! Your message has been successfully sent to the owner of {$email['owner_property']}! You will get an answer soon!";
                    
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "An error has occurred! Please try again ..." . $mail->ErrorInfo;  
                }
    }
}
```

I hope that this answer help somebody too, so if this answer solve your problem too please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Thanks in advance.